# Date format error when use Brazilian Summer Time (BRST)

Tags: java, date, datetime, dst

I'm having a problem when removing the time from a variable date (`Sun Oct 21 01:00:00 BRST 2018`) because it is generating a billing error when a data comes from the database with that 1 hour difference.

This only happens when it is the first day of summer time in Brazil

I've already tried using the `Calendar` class.

```
public static Date zeroTimes( final Date data ) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime( data );
        cal.add( Calendar.HOUR, - 1 );
        return cal.getTime();

    }
```

The return of this method is this `Sun Oct 21 01:00:00 BRST 2018`, 
but what is expected is `Sun Oct 21 00:00:00 BRST 2018`

Comment: First, wouldn’t it be better to correct the error in the datebase instead of trying to fix a wrong hour-of-day later? Second, `Date` and `Calendar` are long outdated classes. You shouldn’t use them anymore. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: First, the date is already going wrong from the code to the database. I know that in java APIS 8 it has much simpler ways to do this, but I can not change the java version I use in the company.

Comment: According to https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/brasilia and a few other home pages summer time starts on November 4, 2018, but your example date is October 21. Have you got an outdated version of the time zone database??

Comment: This is not correct, summer time in brazil starts on October 21, 2018. look at this search [link](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=horario+de+verao+come%C3%A7a+quando+em+2018&oq=horario+de+verao+come%C3%A7a+quando+em+2018&aqs=chrome..69i57.8389j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @HenriqueClerici: As noted in my answer, the rules changed in December 2017. Summer time in 2018 will start on November 4th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- Your JVM has stale time zone data
- You're trying to subtract one hour from 1am where midnight doesn't exist on that date *according to the stale time zone data*.

In December 2017, the Brazilian government changes the rules for daylight saving time so that summer time starts on the first Sunday in November. See [this page in Portuguese](https://noticias.r7.com/economia/por-eleicao-temer-reduz-periodo-de-horario-de-verao-a-partir-de-2018-15122017) or [this page in English](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/brazil-delays-dst-2018.html) for references.

So while summer time in 2018 *actually* starts on November 4th, it looks like your JVM believes it starts on October 21st. If that were the case, 12am wouldn't exist, so 1am would be shown as the start of that date. You haven't told us what value you've got in the `Date` object, but I expect that to be the problem.

Firstly, I'd stop using `java.util.Date` if you possibly can. The `java.time` types are *much* better, in many ways. Use the [JSR-310 backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) if you're stuck on an old version of Java.

Secondly, update your time zone data. See [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) for more information.

Thirdly, work out how you want to handle DST transitions. This is somewhere we probably can't give much advice other than a) think about it explicitly; b) write lots of tests. The exact details of what you'll need to do will depend on your business rules. (It's very likely in my experience that the person who decides those business rules may not have thought about this yet either. Don't let them hand-wave it away: demand precise specifications. Politely, of course :)

Comment: Wonderful answer. Allow me to add that `java.time` includes `LocalDate`, a date without time of day, and `LocalDateTime`, a date and time without time zone. I figure they may be part of a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to subtract the hours would it be easier to set to midnight directly?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(data);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

return(new Date(cal.getTime().getTime()));
```

Comment: I've tried this before but it did not work. The return was Sun Oct 21 01:00:00 BRST 2018

Answer (score 0):

On the day that summer time (horário de verão) begins in Brazil, the clock is moved forward by 1 hour from 00:00 to 01:00. This means that there is no time of 00:00, it doesn’t exist. So I am sorry, you cannot have that.

Comment: You've commented saying that the change is on November 4th, not October 21st - which is what I'd expect as well. I'm not quite sure how this answer ties in with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly: is your date correct for BRST change? Internet claims it's
   **4th of November 2018**.
2. Secondary: the day length of the day when you change to summer time
   lasts only **23h**, so perhaps for billing purposes you have to reconsider how you calculate billing if it is done per hourly.

Comment: 1. This is not correct, summer time in brazil starts on October 21, 2018. look at this search [link](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=horario+de+verao+come%C3%A7a+quando+em+2018&oq=horario+de+verao+come%C3%A7a+quando+em+2018&aqs=chrome..69i57.8389j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
2. Yes, that's what I'm thinking, I do not think I can change that since it starts with 23 hours

Comment: @HenriqueClerici: Those sources are out of date. See https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/brazil-delays-dst-2018.html. It's quite possible that your JVM is using old time zone data.